# How to enable java syntax check in eclipse 3.5?

Tags: java, eclipse

Because I installed a plugin, the java syntax check function is disabled.
Does anyone know where I could enable this? such as: in Window > Preferences.

Thanks 
Joseph

Comment: Which plug-in? It sounds like the plug-in is broken...

Comment: I have asked Aptana support for help. But got no answer.
https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/1587-the-eclipse-native-syntax-alert-function-is-disabled-after-i-install-aptana-20

Comment: Just completed my answer with Aptana-related advice.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [nature of your project](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Builders/builders.html): if java is no longer part of it, that would explain why there is no longer any Java syntax checking.
(same principle than this [blog entry on php nature](http://cesaric.com/?p=369))

Regarding [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/), I don't see any [obvious ticket](https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/45260-rr3/tickets) on this issue.
Check the perspective you are in.
It may be a new perspective (for PHP or ruby development) in which all Java-related feature are disabled.